# Why is multi-threaded slower than single-threaded?

Tags: c, pthreads, openmp, matrix-multiplication

I wrote a parallel pthreads program computing the column sum norm of the product of
two n*n sized matrices. The right matrix is vertically partitioned. The user inputs the matrix size n and the number of threads(p) so that:

1. pthreads are involved in the parallel computations.
2. The 1-dimensional parallel algorithm of matrix multiplication is employed:
3. the right matrix is partitioned in one dimension into p equal slices(A*B, then B is partitioned into p slices)
4. there is one-to-one mapping between the partitions and threads
5. each thread is responsible for computation of the corresponding slice of the resulting matrix

The code:

```
double *A;
double *B;
double *C;
int n;
double matrix_norm;

typedef struct {
   double *b;
   double *c;
   int num_of_columns;
   pthread_mutex_t *mutex;
} matrix_slice;

void *matrix_slice_multiply(void *arg){
   matrix_slice *slice = arg;
   int i, j;
   cblas_dgemm(CblasRowMajor, CblasNoTrans, CblasNoTrans, n, slice->num_of_columns, n, 1.0, A, n, slice->b, n, 0.0, slice->c, n);

   // compute column norm of each slice
   double slice_norm = 0.0;
   for(j = 0; j < slice->num_of_columns; j++) {
      double column_sum=0.;
      for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
         column_sum += *(slice->c + i * n + j);

      if(column_sum>slice_norm)
         slice_norm=column_sum;
   }
   pthread_mutex_lock(slice->mutex);
   if (slice_norm>matrix_norm)
      matrix_norm=slice_norm;
   pthread_mutex_unlock(slice->mutex);

   pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(void) {
   int num_of_thrds, num_of_columns_per_slice;
   pthread_t *working_thread;
   matrix_slice *slice;
   pthread_mutex_t *mutex;
   int i = 0;

   printf ("Please enter matrix dimension n : "); 
   scanf("%d", &n); 

   printf ("Please enter number of threads : "); 
   scanf("%d", &num_of_thrds);

   while (num_of_thrds > n) {
      printf("number of threads must not be greater than matrix dimension\n");
      printf ("Please enter number of threads : "); 
      scanf("%d", &num_of_thrds);
   }
   // allocate memory for the matrices
   ///////////////////// Matrix A //////////////////////////
   A = (double *)malloc(n * n * sizeof(double));

   if (!A) {
      printf("memory failed \n");
      exit(1);
   }

   ///////////////////// Matrix B //////////////////////////
   B = (double *)malloc(n * n * sizeof(double));  
   if (!B) {
      printf("memory failed \n");
      exit(1);
   }

   ///////////////////// Matrix C //////////////////////////
   C = (double *)malloc(n * n * sizeof(double)); 
   if (!C) {
      printf("memory failed \n");
      exit(1);
   }

   // initialize the matrices
   for (i = 0; i < n * n; i++) {        
      A[i] = rand() % 15;
      B[i] = rand() % 10;       
      C[i] = 0.;
   }

   clock_t t1 = clock();    
   working_thread = malloc(num_of_thrds * sizeof(pthread_t));
   slice = malloc(num_of_thrds * sizeof(matrix_slice));
   mutex = malloc(sizeof(pthread_mutex_t));
   num_of_columns_per_slice = n / num_of_thrds;

   for(i = 0; i < num_of_thrds; i++){
      slice[i].b = B + i * num_of_columns_per_slice;
      slice[i].c = C + i * num_of_columns_per_slice;
      slice[i].mutex = mutex;
      slice[i].num_of_columns = (i == num_of_thrds - 1) ? n-i * num_of_columns_per_slice : num_of_columns_per_slice;
      pthread_create(&working_thread[i], NULL, matrix_slice_multiply, (void *)&slice[i]);
   }
   for(i = 0; i < num_of_thrds; i++)
      pthread_join(working_thread[i], NULL);

   clock_t t2=clock();
   printf("elapsed time: %f\n", (double)(t2 - t1)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);   

   printf("column sum norm is %f\n", matrix_norm);  

   //deallocate memory  
   free(A);   
   free(B);   
   free(C);       
   free(working_thread);
   free(slice);

   return 0;
}
```

I ran the program dozens of times with various inputs and it turned out that the more threads used, the more time it cost. This is quite counter-intuitive. Shouldn't more threads help improve the performance?

Comment: Well, you are using clock() to measure time, which will measure the total CPU time, not the wall clock time.

Comment: Which are the dimensions of your matrices? Creating a thread causes some overhead; if you matrices are not big enough then maybe that overhead is bigger than the savings obtained by multithreading.

Comment: as a suggestion: please indent the code next time, this is unreadable

Comment: thank you very much, nos. your answer is exactly what i want. i'll definitely use wall-clock time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The savings from running computations in parallel needs to be greater than the overhead of creating, maintaining, and switching between the threads. Instead of running dozens of times with a large number of threads, run a single very large operation one time with the same number of threads as there are cores on your system.

Comment: You're welcome. If one of the answers helped you, you should click the check mark next to that answer to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Using threads when performing operations that may cause the program to wait for a resource, such as read/write to file system or network, can help improving the performance of your application, but if there are no such operations, the overhead of creating thread, acquiring and releasing mutexes and performing the context switches between the threads might make the application slower.